# Problema con la configuración de SSL Free para Prestashop

Tags: hosting, prestashop, ssl, certificado-ssl

Tengo una eCommerce que esta en proceso de implementación (www.tiendamedicauca.com), esta creada en prestashop y debo agregar el certificado SSL gratuito que me brinda el proveedor de hosting (inmotion hosting), me comunique con el soporte de inmotion y me notificaron que ya se había realizado el proceso y que no debía demorar más de 20 minutos, sin embargo ya paso 6 horas y aun no se activa.

Estuve leyendo y dice que puede ser por los complementos de seguridad en el sistema de administración de contenido. Pueden por favor ayudarme para saber donde están estos complementos? porque dice que debo desactivarlos temporalmente mientras se realiza el proceso.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay poca información sobre el problema. ¿Has comprobado en Preferencias -> Configuración si tienes el control de "Activar SSL" activado?

Comment: Así es, ya esta activado, hice algunas configuraciones en el .htacces pero ahora tengo la duda de si con la configuración debe quedar el candado verde o puede ser una bolita como se muestra en el dominio (www.tiendamedicauca.com), el ssl es free osea que es básico por eso tengo la duda.

Comment: Inspeccionando el código de la url que me pasas, veo que tienes llamadas hacia "http" en vez de hacia "https", esto rompe la cadena SSL y por eso no te sale el candado en el navegador, si le das al candado verás que te dice que la conexión no es completamente segura. Inspecciona y detecta qué imagenes y/o urls estás llamando desde http y reemplázalas por https

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto